# Bootsrap v4.1: Closing a collapse menu when clicking outside of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm in the process of trying to develop code for a plug and play `Mega-Menu`. I've found that using the collapse method seems to be pretty effective for this.

I'm still stuck on figuring out how to close the collapsed item when clicking outside the menu. I'm a beginner level in Javascript so using jquery is slightly challenging.

**Edit**: recently I ran into a better piece of code that isn't a mix of Javascript and JQuery. I tried applying it but still cannot figure out how to properly target the `.collapse()` method.

The widget below has some other issue not sure if it's related to my code since I have had issues with it displaying information incorrectly before. Try this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zy9g2x8c/3/).

**JQuery (Edited):**

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $("#mega-menu");

  // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    //alert("hi");
    container.collapse();
    //$('.collapse').collapse()
  }
```

---

**Code:**

```css
.dropdown-mega-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.mega-menu-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mega-menu-toggle::after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: .255em;
  vertical-align: .255em;
  content: "";
  border-top: .3em solid;
  border-right: .3em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: .3em solid transparent;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-mega-menu {
    position: static;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-md sticky-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link mega-menu-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mega-menu" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="mega-menu">Dropdown link</a>
          <div class="dropdown-mega-menu collapse multi-collapse" id="mega-menu">
            <h3>Heading</h3>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md">
                <div>
                  Other none linked content.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: why keeping the old text ? simply remove it and keep the new issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif, because the issue I thought that was related to the collapse class is actually occuring due to the Javascript. So knowing one of the issues that occur I figure might give someone an idea what is wrong or on the other hand they might just need the code and not the fluff. I could drop the strikethrough title, that was more for people who saw it before the edit

Comment: Who needs constructive criticism when you have a downvote button.. I see asking questions on this website still hasn't changed. Edits will be made to the post to better display the current issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon further investigation I believe I was using the collapse method incorrectly. Using the existing JQuery and adding `collapse('hide')` seems to do the job:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) 
{
    var container = $("#mega-menu");

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.collapse('hide');
    }
});
```